# ListPlot3D: make certain data points have a specific color, whilst the rest of the data is coloured

Tags: plotting, color

I have a 3D data set and would like to color the ListPlot3D but have all the values equal to zero show up as a single colour. For example, having the non-zero points here stay the same, but the surrounding areas to be gray, for example. Thank you in advance for any advice.

[image]

Comment: Change the `ColorFunction` to be something like `With[{cf=ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient"]}, If[#==0., GrayLevel[.8], cf[#]]&]`

Comment: add the options `PlotRange -> {0, All}` and `ClippingStyle -> Gray`?

Comment: @kglr that's just what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: j.foobles, you are welcome. I posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, 0.1}, {j, 0, Pi, 0.1}];
```

You can use the options `PlotRange -> {0, All}` and `ClippingStyle -> Gray`:

```
ListPlot3D[data, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None,
 PlotRange -> {0, All},  
 ClippingStyle -> Gray]
```

[image]